# Bluetooth not working after latest update 5.56-0ubuntu4.2

Tags: bluetooth, dell, xps

The bluez change 5.56-0ubuntu4.2 has caused bluetooth to become completely unavailable on my Dell XPS 13 9300.
gnome-control-center says "No Bluetooth Found", "Plug in a gongle to use Bluetooth."

Downgrading the bluez and libbluetooth3 back to 5.56-0ubuntu4.1 resolves the issue.

I am using ubuntu 21.04.

The issue might be this change:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1933221?comments=all

Am I alone? or is there some other setting I accidentally have on that is causing it to not find the adaptor?

Comment: I'm running into this exact issue, how exactly did you downgrade :)

Comment: Because the update was in the security repository, the original version was still in the main repo. I was able to install a specific version with `apt install <package name>=<version>`